# react-pdf canvas dynamic drawer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

i am working on project for engineering drawing and I need to take measurement from pdf drawings, I found [react-pdf](https://react-pdf.org/components#canvas) where I can use the Canvas component to draw on top of the PDF.

I can't see in the documents how to use the mouse to draw line on square etc.
i make to draw this shape but it's static:

```js
<Canvas
  style={styles.canvas}
  paint={
    (painterObject) =>
      painterObject
        .save()
        .moveTo(100, 100) //move to position 100,100
        .lineTo(300, 100) //draw a line till 300, 100
        .lineTo(300, 300) //draw another line till 300,300
        .fill("red") //when the diagram is drawn, set the background color to pink
  }
/>
```